# Does Grails allow Declarative Exception Handling with Filters?

Tags: grails, exception, authorization, servlet-filters, before-filter

I'd like to create an `AuthorizationFilter` in my Grails app that will inspect request parameters and determine whether a user is authorized to proceed with a request.  I was hoping I could throw a custom exception from within my `AuthorizationFilter` and later handle it with Grails declarative execption handling via a route like:

```
"403"(controller: 'error', action: 'status403', exception:AuthException)
```

... but turns out when I try this in grails 2.2.4 (and the latest dev snapshot) I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name must not be null
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.retrieveAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:41)
```

So... is there any good way to use declarative exception handling together with filters?

Comment: Quick tip: If you are modifying the UrlMappings then prefer a grails clean and then run-app. I tested the implementation again right now, and it does work as expected. If required I can share the project/code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can handle declarative exception from `Controllers` but `Filters`. You can use response instead to send the error code

```
class AuthorizationFilters {
    def filters = {
        auth(controller: 'error', invert: true) {
            before = {
                if(1){ //If auth fails
                    response.sendError(403)
                    //render(status: 403) //or
                    //redirect(controller: 'error', action: 'status403') //or
                }
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above logic will render the response from ErrorController's `status403` action based on the `UrlMapping` that is provided in the question

Make sure you are excluding `error` controller from filters.