# What triggers Grails HTTP status-based exception mapping?

Tags: grails, error-handling, routes

If I have a `UrlMappings.groovy` that specifies:

```
"403"(controller: 'error', action: 'status403')
```

... then I was hoping to trigger this route at runtime by assigning:

```
response.status = 403
```

from within a controller or filter. But that doesn't happen.  Is there a similarly declarative way for me to "kick a request over" to 403 handling from within a controller or filter?

Comment: response.status works just fine in controllers. For filters use @dmahapatro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`response.sendError(403)`

or

`render(status: 403)`

See your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514369/2051952).

Comment: These statements cause a `403` response to be returned, but they do not invoke my `ErrorController`'s `status403` method.  (My goal is to only write down the logic for rendering a 403 in one place.)

Comment: My stopgap is `forward controller: 'error', action: 'status403'`, but it feels wrong.

Comment: @Bosh Did you see my answer to your other question?

Comment: I did, and accepted. But the answer to that question is basically "you can't have declarative error handling from Filters".  Which is fine.  But *this* question asks: even if I can't have declarative error handling, how can I write my error handling logic in *just one place*?  Does `forward` seem like the right approach?

Comment: @Bosh May be I am not getting your question fully. Correct me if i am wrong. The other question took care of the authentication logic (forwarding the user to error controller on failed authentication). You are handling all errors in ErrorController (as different actions like satus500, status404 etc). To reach the error controller for respective actions, you just need to do `response.sendError(500)` or  `response.sendError(404)` etc from other controllers or filters. If I am deviating from your question, then can you give an example here as to what you are expecting. I would be glad to help. :)

Comment: When I call `response.sendError(403)`, that doesn't cause the code in my `ErrorController` to be invoked.  It just returns a default 403. I was hoping to ensure that my `ErrorController`'s `status403` code would be invoked. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bosh Did you exclude the `ErrorController` from the filter as I had mentioned in the other question? It worked for me perfectly, I was able to hit `ErrorController`. We can continue with comments in the other questions if you want.

Comment: Yeah, my filter only includes one controller (not `Error`).  I'll investigate a bit and reply here.